# efficiency of duplicating content and hiding vs cloning via javascript.

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, dom-manipulation

I am using Twitter bootstrap and have a templated menu area that shows in different areas depending on the screen size.

Which would provide the best browser efficiency? Render the menu area in two different areas and show/hide based on the sizes or to use javascript to clone the original menu area and place it in a page when breakpoints are met?

It would seem simpler to just create multiple the multiple divs on original render and then manipulate hide/show as needed, but I am looking for other perspectives.

Comment: Bootstrap handles responsiveness already. If you need to modify it, why not use their media queries and have css decide where to put things?

Comment: >and have css decide where to put things?

The menu display is in quite a dramatically different area and div. No matter... there will be some use of the bootstrap size changes, but where it is being displayed is the main issue.

Comment: CSS is more than capable of moving an element to any location on the screen, not just sizing. If it's that different you'll probably just have to implement both and compare for yourself.

Comment: I don't think there is a always valid answer. It depends on context. If the html structure is incompatible between devices and it's short in terms of rows, you should use two different markup with media query to show/hide them. If the difference concerns only visual you should use a common html structure.